# RMySQL Database connection

Tags: r, rmysql

I'm trying to set up the initial database connection between R and MySQL. I installed RMySQL. When I try to connect to my database, this is the error I receive.

Any direction in fixing it is much appreciated! The package is still quite new so help on this is a little difficult to find. (I'm also new to R).

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), group = "Mydatabase")
```

> Error in .local(drv, ...) 
>   Failed to connect to database Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (0)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you have a proper MySQL database set up and you need to pass the config options of that database to the `dbConnect` call.  Is there a MySQL database on that machine?

I think if you use the `group` parameter, then `RMySQL` will assume you have a configuration file with settings for a `Mydatabase` database. I forget how to set up that file, but this is how I connect to `RMySQL`:

```
  db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = DB_NAME,
                  host = options()$mysql$host,
                  port = options()$mysql$port,
                  user = options()$mysql$user,
                  password = options()$mysql$password)
```

(in my .Rprofile I set up all these options). After you have all these values (dbname, host, port, user, pw) for your database, try running this command

Comment: Hi, yes I have MSSQL on my computer. My login for it is through Windows Authentication, not SQL Server Authentication

Comment: I don't know how that works , you'll have to figure out these values for your specific database

Comment: Oh my, I didn't notice that you said MS instead of My. Yes @hadley is right